# Dimension of a direct sum of characters (example with $S_3$)

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, characters

Here is the character table of $S_3$:
[image: Character table of S3]

I was wondering how one can determine the dimension of for example the sign character $sgn$. Could we get it from the character table?

Also, if we define $A$ to be $A=sgn\oplus V$, where $V$ is the standard character. What would be the dimension of $A$ be?

Thank you for your time

Edit: I *think* it may be given in the first column of the character table... Since these are the degrees of the irreducible representations/characters

Comment: Out of curiosity, what book/notes are you using? You can take direct sums of modules and representations, but the corresponding characters you get are literally *just* sums.

Comment: Well the motivation behind this is induced representations. For example, if $G=S_4$ and $H=S_3$, I calculated using the character tables, that say $Ind_H^G (1)=V \oplus 1$. Some past exams for my representation theory course ask to find the dimension of $Ind(X_i)$  and I was wondering how to do this.... Does this make sense? Maybe I am mistaken in viewing the decomposition as characters. I seem to remember my lecturer saying we could find the dimension of $Ind$ by considering the degrees of the individual elements involved... Id really like to be able to figure how to calculate the dimension

Comment: I think it may depend on values in values of character table but i am not sure

Comment: I was hinting that you should go back to the definitions. Given representations $\mathcal{X}\colon G \to \Bbb C^n$ and $\mathcal{Y}\colon G \to \Bbb C^m$ of $G$, we have their direct sum

\begin{align*}
\mathcal{X} \oplus \mathcal{Y}\colon G &\to C^{m + n} \cong \Bbb C^m \oplus \Bbb C^n \\
g &\mapsto \pmatrix{\mathcal{X}(g) & 0 \\ 0 & \mathcal{Y}(g)}.
\end{align*} Can you relate the traces of the direct sum to traces of the summands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The degree of a representation is another name for its dimension, so yes, the (initial) column for the identity element gives the dimension. (This is because the trace of an identity operator is the dimension of the space it acts upon.) And the dimension of a direct sum of representations is the sum of the dimension of the summands, like for any direct sum.